# What's the difference between respected and respectable?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, british-english, passive-voice, linguistics

> He is highly [respected/respectable] owing to his good manners and
>   gratefulness.

I know the difference but I can't decide which one to choose, either he is respected (the passive form)or he is respectable as he has got good manners.

Comment: Welcome to ELU site. Please read first http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and make your question more like this :)

Comment: A guy holding a gun to your head is "respected" (if you know what's good for you).  But likely he's not "respectable".

Comment: So what's the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Respectable" strictly means "worth respecting", although it more frequently means something like "conforms to societal norms".

"Respected" means that people do actually respect them.

Sometimes these are not the same thing. For example a person who does everything that is required by society, yet for some reason is not liked, may be *respectable* but not *respected*. A highly intelligent critic who refuses to conform to society's values may be *respected* but not *respectable*.

Comment: So the answer should be respectable as he actually has good manners?

Comment: I'm not sure the meaning of respectable is as strict as you say.

Answer (score 5):

***Respected*** is the past participle form of *respect*. It can be parsed as the passive past participle, implying: *People (the implied agent) respect him highly, because of his etiquette and gratitude*. Others might want to parse *respected* as a predicate adjective, but that would be a redundant manipulation of the participial form.

***Respectable*** is the adjectival derivative of *respect* with the suffix *[-able](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-able)*:

> SUFFIX
>
> Forming adjectives meaning:
>
> 1. Able to be:
>
> *calculable*
>
> 2. Due to be:
>
> *payable*
>
> 3. Subject to:
>
> *taxable*
>
> 4 Relevant to or in accordance with:
>
> *fashionable*
>
> 5. Having the quality to:
>
> *comfortable*

*[Respectable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/respectable)* carries a meaning very similar to *respected*:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1.0 Regarded by society to be good, proper, or correct:
>
> *They thought the stage no life for a respectable lady.*
>
> 1.1 (Of a person’s appearance, clothes, or behavior) decent or presentable:

In some situations the participial adjective *respected* and the derivative *respectable* can create a *subtle distinction* between *the way people feel about it* and *the quality that makes them feel that way*. Sometimes that distinction is overlooked.

---

www.oxforddictionaries.com

Comment: Considering "the quality that makes them feel that way", would it be better to say "the ability to make them feel that way?"

Comment: That would be an acceptable expression, but the fifth entry under the suffix  is ***having the quality to***.